# Seemingly strange behavior with python counter program

Tags: python, date, iterator

A portion of a recent assignment was to design a program that counts days between dates. I have yet to finish, and I know this could be improved drastically. However, my question is: when I run this program with **date2** (below), an error occurs, but this runs as planned with **date1** (again, below). I find this behavior strange. These dates are only one day apart and yet one fails and one doesn't. I've tried this with multiple dates, but each fails after 994 days regardless of month, year, day, whatever. **Why?**

clarification: I define "fail" as

```
  File "first.py", line 35, in counter
    return counter(date_array, x+1)
```

.

```
def date_test(date_array):
    first = (date_array[0], date_array[1], date_array[2])
    second = (date_array[3], date_array[4], date_array[5])
    if first > second:
        return False
    elif first != second:
        return True
    elif first == second:
        return False
    else:
        return "Error: This shouldn't happen."

def counter(date_array, x = 0):
    months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    while(date_test(date_array)):
        if(date_array[2] == 31 and date_array[1] == 12):
            date_array[0] += 1; date_array[1], date_array[2] = 1, 1
            return counter(date_array, x+1)
        else:
            if date_array[2] < months[date_array[1]-1]:
                date_array[2] += 1
                return counter(date_array, x+1)
            else:
                date_array[1] += 1; date_array[2] = 1;
                return counter(date_array, x+1);
    return x

def tuple_test(date):
    date_array = []
    for x in date:
        date_array.append(x)
    if not date_test(date_array):
       return "The first date is before the second. Swap them."
    return counter(date_array)

date1 = (1900,1,1,1902,9,22)
date2 = (1900,1,1,1902,9,23)

print tuple_test(date1)
print tuple_test(date2)
```

Comment: Neither of them work for me.

Comment: Use comments; only run one at a time. I do this and experience the behavior I described above.

Comment: Running either one throws an error that says that `counter` exceeded the maximum recursion depth.

Comment: I feel as if I should use recursion to ask another question about why your output in my program isn't the same as my output.

Comment: The maximum recursion depth on my Python install is 1000. It's probably higher on yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you've exceeded your maximum recursion depth.

To "hack" (and verify) this problem you could simply add

```
import sys 
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

to the top of your code

Comment: Glad that I could help :). If you are satisfied with the answer you could mark the question as "answered". Otherwise people might still try to answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use the tools python provides

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date1 = (1900,1,1,1902,9,22) #your weird list with 2 dates
>>> dt1 = datetime.date(*date1[:3]) #create a date object  == datetime.date(1900,1,1)
>>> dt2 = datetime.date(*date1[3:]) #create a date object  == datetime.date(1902,9,22)
>>> if dt1 < dt2: dt1,dt2 = dt2,dt1 #if dt1 is smaller than dt2, swap them
...
>>> print (dt1 - dt2).days #subtract them and print their days
994
>>>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that existed. Thank you. Although, I think this assignment was about learning the hard way.

Comment: what makes you think that? ... it sounds like a pretty straight forward assignment ... part of the assignment is to use recursion?

Comment: I think the goal was to force the student to create their own functions as opposed to using (lacking term) one (defined?) in python.